# SiteDescription managed property inside the display template will always show the site description in a single line

Tags: 2013, development, display-template, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I have added a content search web part, to show all the sub-sites inside my parent site. and i chose the following properties to be shown:-

[image]

so i chose to show the Path,Title & SiteDescription.
now i have a site description as follow:-

```
This site has the following description:-
1. a
2. B
3. C
```

[image]

but the problem (as shown in the first picture) the site description will rendered as a single line inside the display template. instead of being shown on multiple lines as shown in the site settings page...

So is there a way to show the site description on multiple lines inside the display template as follow:-

```
This site has the following description:-
1. a
2. B
3. C
```

instead of being shown as a single line `This site has the following description:- 1. a 2. B 3. C` ??
Thanks